# Spark installation on memsql cluster

Tags: apache-spark, singlestore

I am trying to install Spark on 3 node memsql cluster using MemSQL Ops but getting below error. Please suggest how to resolve this error.

**Failed to deploy Spark.
Could not get latest version of Spark: There are no SPARK files available.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check that the machine running the MemSQL Primary Agent has access to the internet?  If not you will need to manually provide our Spark distribution to MemSQL Ops before you are able to deploy.  You can do this like so:

```
On a machine with internet:
wget -O spark.tar.gz http://download.memsql.com/memsql-spark-1.4.1-distribution-1.1.1/memsql-spark-1.4.1-distribution-1.1.1.tar.gz
scp spark.tar.gz <PRIMARY AGENT SSH DETAILS>:/tmp/spark.tar.gz

Then on your primary:
memsql-ops file-add -t spark /tmp/spark.tar.gz
memsql-ops spark-deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by manually installing spark using memsql-ops.